# Images classification using SVM classifier

Tags: matlab

I am new in MATLAB,I have centers of training images, and centers of testing images stored in 2-D matrix ,I already extracted color histogram features,then find the centers using K-means clustering algorithm,now I want to classify them using using SVM classifier in two classes Normal and Abnormal,I know there is a built in function in MATLAB but I don't know to adapt it to be used in this job,any help or suggestion will be helpful to me. 
Thank to All

Thank you ,the svmclassify function classifies each row of the data in Sample,but I've represented each image by four rows of centers out of
K-means clustering algorithm,so I don't know how to do training,any help or suggestion will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

To train your SVM classifier, you can use the `svmtrain` function as described [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/stats/svmtrain.html)

To classify your data, you can use the `svmclassify` function as described [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/stats/svmclassify.html)

PS: Do not hesitate to look at the MatLab documentation at the Mathworks website.

Hope this was helpful.